# Vectorized solution for multiple column operation in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, vectorization

i probably will have a large dataframe which has the following first row:

```
   BUCHDAT     y  y1   y2    y3     y4    y5     y6     y7
7 2017-02-26 577 30.0 622.0 1785.0 2633.0 422.0 10497.0 364.0
```

Now i want to replace the columns 'y' till 'y7' with a formula:

`df['y'] = df['y'] - df['y1']`

Is there any vectorization solution for this? So I want to apply this formula in every column, for the next column the formula should be:

`df['y1'] = df['y1']- df['y2']`

you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one working with the underlying numpy arrays for a good performance:

```
df.iloc[:,1:-1] = df.values[:,1:-1] - df.values[:,2:]

print(df)

    BUCHDAT      y     y1      y2     y3      y4       y5       y6     y7
7  2017-02-26  547.0 -592.0 -1163.0 -848.0  2211.0 -10075.0  10133.0  364.0
```

Comment: This is great usage of arrays, would you mind to add some explanation? +1

Comment: Yes well its really basic slicing @erfan that's why I didn't add details. I'm subtracting the following column to current column up until the one before the last

Comment: this solution is faster: 0.0 seconds, this is why i picked it as solution

Comment: I generally do add some explanations. I do consider though that having to go through the very basics shouldn't be necessary, unless it is evident that OPs level is very low. I don't think I should be adding how slicing notation works. Don't you think so @erfan?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:].astype(float)
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df1.sub(df1.shift(-1, axis=1))
print (df)
      BUCHDAT      y     y1      y2     y3      y4       y5       y6  y7
7  2017-02-26  547.0 -592.0 -1163.0 -848.0  2211.0 -10075.0  10133.0 NaN
```

Comment: is there an option without set the index before and reset it afterwards? I need to keep the Index as a number

Comment: this operation takes: 0.015599966049194336 seconds